# Editing Authselect files

Tags: linux, authentication, fedora, hardening

I'm hardening fedora OS following the CIS Benchmark for fedora 28.

In one of the remediations, the Benchmark provides an script that modifies the files `system-auth` and `password-auth`. When I apply the changes with `authselect apply-changes` I get an error because that files were modified.

Supposedly I can modified these files, but I'm not understanding how to commit the changes. I've been searching about this but stilling stuck.

The error is the next one:

```
[error] [/etc/authselect/password-auth] has unexpected content!
[error] Unexpected changes to the configuration were detected.
[error] Refusing to activate profile unless those changes are removed or overwrite is requested.
Some unexpected changes to the configuration were detected. Use 'select' command instead.
```

Some help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `--force` to force it.

I've added this to ansible post security baseline:

```
- name: enable auto home dirs
  command: "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - authselect select sssd --force
    - authselect select sssd with-mkhomedir
```